# How do I check if a string is contained in an ArrayList?

Tags: java

I have the below code and I want the code to keep executing as long as there is no attempt to enter a word that is already in the array. Instead of doing this it exits after the first word is entered.

```
    do {
        System.out.print("Type a word: ");
        enteredWord = reader.nextLine();
        words.add(enteredWord);
    } while (!words.contains(enteredWord));
```

If I change the bottom line to use a set word such as "test" then the program works fine. I have tried putting print statements for testing in and it showed me the word was set correctly and was present in the array.

Comment: As soon as they enter the first word, you add it to words, so it's now contained in words, so your loop exits...

Comment: Your loop makes no sense. Why wouldn't the arraylist contain the word after you add it?

Comment: Just change it to a simple while loop, so you first check loop condition and then inside you enter a word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add the word in the list before checking the word is in the list.
Try the following :

```
for(;;) {
    System.out.print("Type a word: ");
    enteredWord = reader.nextLine();
     if(words.contains(enteredWord)) {
        break; //ends loop
     }
     words.add(enteredWord);
}
```

Comment: smarx got it before ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do something like:

```
    boolean alreadyThere;
    do {
        System.out.print("Type a word: ");
        enteredWord = reader.nextLine();
        alreadyThere = words.contains(enteredWord);
        words.add(enteredWord);
    } while (!alreadyThere);
```

You decide whether it's already there before you add the word. Of course that can still be improved (using a Set instead of a List, adding the word only if it's not yet there, and so on).

Answer (score 0):

The comments correctly identify the issue. The fix is to check for the presence of the entered word *before* you add it to the list. Here's one possible fix:

```
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Type a word: ");
    enteredWord = reader.nextLine();
    if (words.contains(enteredWord)) {
        break;
    }
    words.add(enteredWord);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice everyone. As was said straight away I was adding a word to the array and then checking if it was added so it was exiting. Rookie mistake. I went with the below solution.

```
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Type a word: ");
        enteredWord = reader.nextLine();
        if (!words.contains(enteredWord)) {
            words.add(enteredWord);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
```